# MYSQL Query - joining tables and grouping results

Tags: mysql

I'm after some help with a report I'm designing please.
My report includes results from a booking database where I'd like to show each booking on a single line. However as the booking database has a number of tables my MYSQL query involves JOINS which is resulting in multiple rows per booking. It is the multiple results for "dcea4_eb_field_values.field_value" per booking causing the repeating rows.

This is my query

```
SELECT 
dcea4_eb_events.event_date,
dcea4_eb_events.title,
dcea4_eb_registrants.id,
dcea4_eb_registrants.first_name,
dcea4_eb_registrants.last_name,
dcea4_eb_registrants.email,
dcea4_eb_registrants.register_date,
dcea4_eb_registrants.amount,
dcea4_eb_registrants.comment,
dcea4_eb_field_values.field_id,
dcea4_eb_field_values.field_value
FROM dcea4_eb_events
INNER JOIN dcea4_eb_registrants ON dcea4_eb_registrants.event_id = dcea4_eb_events.id
INNER JOIN dcea4_eb_field_values ON dcea4_eb_field_values.registrant_id = dcea4_eb_registrants.id
WHERE 1=1 
AND (dcea4_eb_field_values.field_id = 14 OR dcea4_eb_field_values.field_id = 26 OR dcea4_eb_field_values.field_id = 27 OR dcea4_eb_field_values.field_id = 15)
AND dcea4_eb_registrants.published <> 2
AND dcea4_eb_registrants.published IS NOT NULL
AND (dcea4_eb_registrants.published = 1 OR dcea4_eb_registrants.payment_method = "os_offline")
[ AND (dcea4_eb_registrants.register_date {RegistrationDate} ) ]
[ AND REPLACE(dcea4_eb_events.title,'\'','') in ({Club}) ] 
ORDER BY dcea4_eb_registrants.register_date, 
dcea4_eb_events.title
```

This is what the output currently looks like
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAeSn.png)

and this is what I'd like it to look like
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXLdH.png)

Any help appreciated